# Updating data in Excel workbook with data in an other workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook Called Price list, it contain several worksheets each worksheet is in the same format but contain different classifications of products. The format of a work sheet is as folows:

> ```
>  A          B          C      D
> ```
>
> 1    PRC      DESCRIPTION  UNIT  PRICE
>
> 2   A001      Product1     Each    20.00
>
> 3   D001      Product2      L       5.00
>
> 4   H001      Product3      Rol     4.00

Every month We get an Updated Price List as an Exel workbook.

In the past we got all the information as above but something changed at the Supplier and we only receive the "Product code" "Bar-code" and "Price"

I need to update my **"Price-list"** by matching the Product Code in the **"Update"** with the one in my Price list. Then compare price, if the price differs it should change the price in the **"Price-list"** to that of the **"Update"**

If posible it should delete the line in the **"Update"** for us to know if there are new Products and delete the Line in the **"Price-List"** if the product code is not found in the "Update", For discontinued Products.

The "Update" Contains about 12000 lines

**Is there an easy way in doing it?**

***EDITED TO INCLUDE COMMENTS AND CODE FROM OP***

I wrote some Code But I'm not to clued up with VBA.

```
Sub UpdateMisilanious_Original()
' UpdateMisilanious Macro
' This will update the misilanious List
'The variable for the active line in Misilanious
Dim ALMis As Integer
    ALMis = 4
'The variable for the active line in Update
Dim ALUp As Integer
    ALUp = 2
'The varible for product code of Misilanious
Dim PrCMis As String
'The varible for product code of Update
Dim PrCUp As String
'The temp Varible for the Price
Dim NewPrice As Currency

    'Read the first Product code in Pricelist
    PrCMis = Worksheets("Misilanious").Range("A" & ALMis).Value
    'Start the Loop to update all Products
    Do While PrCMis <> ""
        PrCMis = Worksheets("Misilanious").Range("A" & ALMis).Value
        PrCUp = Worksheets("Update").Range("A" & ALUp).Value
        If PrCMis = PrCUp Then
            'Copy price from Update to Pricelist
            NewPrice = Worksheets("Update").Range("c" & ALUp).Value
            Worksheets("Misilanious").Range("E" & ALMis) = NewPrice
            'Add one to Active line of price list
            ALMis = ALMis + 1
            'Reset Active line of Update
            ALUp = 2
        Else:

            'Loop through update untilmaching Product code is found
            Do Until PrCMis = PrCUp
                ALUp = ALUp + 1
                PrCUp = Worksheets("Update").Range("A" & ALUp).Value
            Loop
            NewPrice = Worksheets("Update").Range("c" & ALUp).Value
            Worksheets("Misilanious").Range("E" & ALMis) = NewPrice
            'Add one to Active line of price list
            ALMis = ALMis + 1
            'Reset Active line of Update
            ALUp = 2
        End If
    Loop
    MsgBox "Update Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: I have the following Idea how it should work:

Comment: I have the following Idea how it should work: Read value of A2 in Price-list save to a variable1. Start loop Read value of A2 in Update and compare with variable1 if = then Read value of C2 in Update and store in variable2 and write variable2 to D2 of Price-list. Then delete line 2 in Update. If A2 in Update not = to Varible1 Then go to next line read A3 and compare with Varible1 extr..  If read value is False meaning no data, end loop and start new loop with next line in Price-list

Comment: Your description of how it should work and the fact that you want to have lines deleted implies use of VBA, however your question is tagged as excel-formula. Are you going for a VBA solution? If so, show us what have you done and what problems are you facing. On the other hand, deleting lines as they are processed it will not allow to audit the process in case something goes wrong, but yet again it just have to do with the level of standards and quality you want to work with. This can be done with formulas, but then you'll have to delete lines manually (if insist on doing it), or with VBA.

Comment: I wrote some Code But I'm not to clued up with VBA .  Now I do not know how to go forward, I want to copy the code here but It is to long

Comment: Sub UpdateMisilanious()   

' UpdateMisilanious Macro   
' This will update the misilanious List   

'The variable for the active line in Misilanious  
Dim ALMis As Integer  
ALMis = 4  
'The variable for the active line in Update  
Dim ALUp As Integer  
ALUp = 2  
'The varible for product code of Misilanious  
Dim PrCMis As String  
'The varible for product code of Update   
Dim PrCUp As String   
'The temp Varible for the Price  
Dim NewPrice As Currency

Comment: 'Read the first Product code in Pricelist
PrCMis = Worksheets("Misilanious").Range("A" & ALMis).Value

'Start the Loop to update all Products
Do While PrCMis <> ""

    PrCMis = Worksheets("Misilanious").Range("A" & ALMis).Value
    PrCUp = Worksheets("Update").Range("A" & ALUp).Value
        If PrCMis = PrCUp Then
            'Copy price from Update to Pricelist
            NewPrice = Worksheets("Update").Range("c" & ALUp).Value
            Worksheets("Misilanious").Range("E" & ALMis) = NewPrice

Comment: 'Add one to Active line of price list
            ALMis = ALMis + 1
            'Reset Active line of Update
            ALUp = 2
        Else:
            'Loop through update untilmaching Product code is found
            Do Until PrCMis = PrCUp
                ALUp = ALUp + 1
                PrCUp = Worksheets("Update").Range("A" & ALUp).Value

Comment: Loop
                NewPrice = Worksheets("Update").Range("c" & ALUp).Value
                Worksheets("Misilanious").Range("E" & ALMis) = NewPrice
                'Add one to Active line of price list
                ALMis = ALMis + 1
                'Reset Active line of Update
                ALUp = 2
        End If

Comment: Loop
MsgBox "Update Done"

End Sub

Comment: Sorry about the mess But I can't format the code nicely that it is more readable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good attempt at writing the code, just a short comment about it:

*This part will loop endlessly if the Product is discontinued…*

```
'Loop through update untilmaching Product code is found
Do Until PrCMis = PrCUp
    ALUp = ALUp + 1
    PrCUp = Worksheets("Update").Range("A" & ALUp).Value
Loop
```

The solution provided below, loop through the products in the **Price List** but the instead of looping again through the **Update**, it finds the matching record. Runs a comparison of **Price List** vs. **Update** identifying new prices and discontinued products, then runs a second comparison from **Update** to **Price List** in order to add new products. Have a look at the procedure below and the suggested readings, hope this will encourage you to continue working on automating all those tedious and repetitive daily tasks.

This solutions uses these three worksheets:

1. **Update**: Contains the latest price update for all products. It may include new products, also *“Discontinued”* products are not included in this list. Its data is a continuous range of cells starting at `E7`, *delimited by blank cells*.
2. **Price List**: Contains the list of all products with respective price and other associated data. Its data is a continuous range of cells starting at `C6`, *delimited by blank cells*.
3. **Discontinued**: Contains the list of the discontinued products. Its data is a continuous range of cells starting at `B2`, *delimited by blank cells*. This worksheet will be created by the procedure if not present.

This code runs a comparison of the Products between the Price List and Update worksheets *(both ways)* and updates *new prices*, adds *new products* and deletes *discontinued products* in the **Price List** data, with track of the updates and keeping a list of the discontinued products in a separated worksheet.

As this code use resources that might be unknown to the user, I have added some indications of their purpose and suggested pages for extended reading and understanding, nevertheless let me know of any question you might have about the code.

[Application Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194565.aspx), 
[For...Next Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg251601.aspx), 
[MsgBox Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251821(v=office.15).aspx),

[Range Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff838238.aspx), 
[Variables & Constants](http://www.excelfunctions.net/VBA-Variables-And-Constants.html), 
[With Statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264723.aspx),

[Worksheets Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821537.aspx), 
[WorksheetFunction Object (Excel)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff834434.aspx)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update_Miscellaneous()

Rem Constants to Hold Starting Cell of Data Ranges (update as required)
'see [Variables & Constants]
Const kIniPlst As String = "C6"
Const kIniUpdt As String = "E7"
Const kIniDisc As String = "B2"

Rem Declare Objects as Variables
'see [Range Object (Excel)]
Dim rUpdt As Range, rMisc As Range, rDisc As Range

Rem Declare Process Variables
Dim sProd As String, dPric As Double, dPOld As Double

Dim Wsh As Worksheet, Rng As Range
Dim bProdUpdt As Byte, bPricUpdt As Byte
Dim bProd As Byte, bPric As Byte, bPOld As Byte, bPStt As Byte
Dim lRow0 As Long, lRow1 As Long, lNew As Long
Dim tTme As Date, sNow As String

    Rem Application Settings To Improve Performance
    'see [Application Object (Excel)]
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Rem Set Time & Date
    tTme = Now
    sNow = Format(Now, " dd-mmm-yy hh:mm")

    Rem Set Objects
    'see [With Statement]
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set rUpdt = .Worksheets("Update").Range(kIniUpdt).CurrentRegion
        Set rMisc = .Worksheets("Price List").Range(kIniPlst).CurrentRegion
        On Error GoTo WshAdd
        Set rDisc = .Worksheets("Discontinued").Range(kIniDisc).CurrentRegion
        On Error GoTo 0
        Set rDisc = rDisc.Rows(1).Offset(rDisc.Rows.Count)
    End With

    Rem Set Field Position - Updated
    'see [WorksheetFunction Object (Excel)]
    With rUpdt
        Rem Set Field Position
        'Using Excel Worksheet Functions in VBA
        bProdUpdt = WorksheetFunction.Match("Product Code", .Rows(1), 0)
        'Can also be used with Application
        bPricUpdt = Application.Match("Price", .Rows(1), 0)
        Rem Set Body Range
        Set rUpdt = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count)
    End With

    Rem Set Field Position - Miscellaneous
    With rMisc
        Rem Set AutoFilter Off
        If Not .Worksheet.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then .AutoFilter
        Rem Set Field Position
        bProd = WorksheetFunction.Match("PRC", .Rows(1), 0)
        bPric = WorksheetFunction.Match("PRICE", .Rows(1), 0)
        bPOld = WorksheetFunction.Match("Price.Old", .Rows(1), 0)
        bPStt = WorksheetFunction.Match("Status", .Rows(1), 0)
        Rem Set Body Range
        Set rMisc = .Offset(1, 0).Resize(-1 + .Rows.Count)
    End With

    Rem Update Current Products
    With rMisc

        Rem Set Latest Price
        'see [For...Next Statement]
        For lRow0 = 1 To .Rows.Count
            sProd = .Cells(lRow0, bProd).Value2
            dPOld = .Cells(lRow0, bPric).Value2

            Rem Get Latest Price
            lRow1 = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            lRow1 = WorksheetFunction.Match(sProd, rUpdt.Columns(bProdUpdt), 0)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If lRow1 <> 0 Then
                Rem Prices Comparison
                dPric = rUpdt.Cells(lRow1, bPricUpdt).Value2
                If dPric <> dPOld Then
                    Rem New Price
                    .Cells(lRow0, bPOld).Value = dPOld
                    .Cells(lRow0, bPric).Value = dPric
                    .Cells(lRow0, bPStt).Value = "Price Change" & sNow
                End If

            Else
                Rem Product Discontinued
                .Cells(lRow0, bPOld).Value = dPOld
                .Cells(lRow0, bPric).ClearContents
                .Cells(lRow0, bPStt).Value = "Discontinued" & sNow

    End If: Next: End With

    Rem Set New Products
    lNew = rMisc.Rows.Count
    With rUpdt
        For lRow0 = 1 To .Rows.Count
            sProd = .Cells(lRow0, bProd).Value2
            dPric = .Cells(lRow0, bPricUpdt).Value2

            Rem Get New Product
            lRow1 = 0
            On Error Resume Next
            lRow1 = WorksheetFunction.Match(sProd, rMisc.Columns(bProdUpdt), 0)
            On Error GoTo 0
            If lRow1 = 0 Then
                Rem Add New Product
                lNew = 1 + lNew
                With rMisc
                    .Cells(lNew, bProd).Value = sProd
                    .Cells(lNew, bPric).Value = dPric
                    .Cells(lNew, bPStt).Value = "!New Product" & sNow

    End With: End If: Next: End With

    Rem Reset Range Misc
    If lNew <> rMisc.Rows.Count Then
        Set rMisc = rMisc.CurrentRegion
        Set rMisc = rMisc.Offset(1, 0).Resize(-1 + rMisc.Rows.Count)
        Debug.Print xlPasteFormats, Now,
        rMisc.Rows(1).Copy
        rMisc.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        Debug.Print Now
    End If

    Rem Move Discontinued Records
    With rMisc

        Rem Sort By Status
        'Sort is a Property of the Worksheet Object
        With .Worksheet.Sort
            .SortFields.Clear
            .SortFields.Add Key:=rMisc.Columns(bPStt), _
                SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
            .SetRange rMisc
            .Header = xlYes
            .MatchCase = False
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .SortMethod = xlPinYin
            .Apply
        End With

        Rem Set AutoFilter
        .CurrentRegion.AutoFilter

        Rem Filter by Status\Discontinued
        .AutoFilter Field:=bPStt, Criteria1:="=*Discontinued*"
        On Error Resume Next
        Set Rng = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0

        Rem Set AutoFilter Off
        If Not .Worksheet.AutoFilter Is Nothing Then .AutoFilter

        Rem Work with Discontinued Records
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then

            Rem Add Discontinued Records
            rDisc.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count).Value = Rng.Value2
            rDisc.CurrentRegion.Columns.AutoFit
            Application.Goto rDisc.Worksheet.Cells(1), 1
            Application.Goto rDisc.Cells(1)

            Rem Delete Discontinued Records
            'Rng.EntireRow.Delete       'Use this line if no other data in worksheet
            Rng.Delete Shift:=xlUp     'Use this line if there is other data in worksheet

    End If: End With

    Rem Sort Remaining Records By Product
    With rMisc.Worksheet.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=rMisc.Columns(bProd), _
            SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .SetRange rMisc
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    Rem Restate Application Settings
    Application.Goto rMisc.Worksheet.Cells(1), 1
    Application.Goto rMisc.Cells(1)
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    'see [MsgBox Function]
    Rem Process Completed
    MsgBox "Update Completed in " & Format(Now - tTme, "hh : mm : ss.001"), _
        vbApplicationModal + vbInformation + vbOKOnly, _
        "Product Price Update"

Exit Sub
WshAdd:
    'see [Worksheets Object (Excel)]
    Rem Add Worksheet Discontinued
    With ThisWorkbook
        Set Wsh = .Sheets.Add(After:=.Sheets(.Sheets.Count))
    End With
    Wsh.Name = "Discontinued"
    Wsh.Range(kIniDisc).Resize(, rMisc.Columns.Count).Value = rMisc.Rows(1).Value2
    Resume

End Sub
```

[image: Price List before update]

Fig.1 Price List before update

[image: Update data]

Fig.2 Update data

[image: Price List after update]

Fig. 3 Price list after update

[image: Discontinued after update]

Fig. 4 Discontinued after update

Comment: Thank you EEM, your code runs fine, I will use that as a base to learn more VBA.

Comment: Glad to know it encourage you, we can assist you in the process, keep posting your questions...